# How to make search engines to take care more about exclusive contents?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

We have a website that lots of our contents are from other sources and we also have a link to those sources at the bottom of each content, but recently we started to generate content by ourselves, which means we're going to have more exclusive content which is written inside out own company.

There are two questions here:

1- How to let Google clearly knows that those contents are from those sources? (I'm worried about the negative point from Google)

2- How to let Google know this is exclusive content, and different from rest of contents on the website? (any meta-tag or tag?)

Comment: Do you have permission to add their content to your site? a link to the source does not make it legal and Google may receive DCMA complaints and your rankings will plummet big time. If you do have permission then you should look for canonical links.

Comment: Also, we already have various questions and answers regarding SEO and external duplicate content.

Comment: @SimonHayter What does canonical has to do with duplicate content? could you guide me please

Comment: Canonical tells search engines where the master copy is stored. You can find this information by searching canonical links on Pro Webmasters and on Google.